# Session_start() after defining a constant

Tags: php, session

on every page (first lines, first code) I have those two lines of code:

```
define("DIRECT_ACCESS", true);
defined("DIRECT_ACCESS") OR die(header("Location: https://website.com/"));
```

after those two lines of code, I always do session_start();, I read that session_start() should come as a first thing, before anything. Session_status() shows that session is active and working properly, so I have a couple of questions:

**1. Why does the session work if it should be the first line, before other code?**
**2. Is there anything dangerous that  can happen, could something stop working later if I don't put session_start() as the first line of code?**

Thanks for your time trying to help me.

Comment: `session_start()` has to be above output. Not exactly in the first line.

Comment: Sessions are usually handled with cookies. So you should not send any byte before starting session. This will disturb the header.

Comment: So can I keep the code as is it now or should I move the session_start()? If it declares constants and doesn't produce any output then it is "safe" if I understood you correctly?

Comment: "if it should be the first line, before other code" - who told you that?

Comment: Yes, that's wrong, but the answer below cleared that up for me. @NicoHaase

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I read that `session_start()` should come as a first thing, before anything.

That statement is basically wrong.

There're a few things to take into account when initialising sessions:

1. With the default (and recommended) settings, session ID is transmitted through a cookie. Server-side cookies are set through HTTP headers. HTTP headers need to be sent before response body. Thus you need to avoid constructs like this:

   ```
   echo 'Hello, World!';
   session_start();
   ```
2. You cannot use session data before it's retrieved from the persistent storage. That's precisely what `session_start()` does. So you cannot do this:

   ```
   $user_name = $_SESSION['user_name'];
   session_start();
   ```
3. Some times you may want to close the session in order to unlock the storage. You do that with `session_write_close()`. Once you do that, session data remains loaded but changes won't persist. So please avoid:

   ```
   session_write_close();
   $_SESSION['user_name'] = 'john.doe';
   ```

Other than that, you're free to start sessions whenever you see fit.